# Start with new line after certain amount of characters in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, stringbuilder, bufferedwriter

I have a program which reads a file I can change the content of this file and after that it's written to another file. The input file looks like this: http://gyazo.com/4ee1ade01378238e2c765e593712de7f and the output has to look like this http://gyazo.com/5a5bfd00123df9d7791a74b4e77f6c10 my current output is http://gyazo.com/87a83f4c6d48aebda3d11060ebad66c2 so how to change my code that it's starts a new line after 12 characters? Also I want to delete the last !.

```
    public class readFile {

        String line;
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();


        public void readFile(){

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/Sybren/Desktop/Invoertestbestand1.txt");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        //String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        //buf.append(line);
        processInput();
        }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        try {
        reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        };
        }
        }
        public void processInput(){

        buf.append(line);  

        if (buf.length()>7){
        buf.append("-");
        //buf.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

        /* start with a new line if the line length is bigger than 12 - in progress*/
        /* I know this if doesn't work but how to fix it? */
        if (buf.length()>12){
        buf.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

        /* if a * is followed by * change them to a !*/
        for (int index = 0; index < buf.length(); index++) {
        if (buf.charAt(index) == '*' && buf.charAt(index+1) == '*') {
        buf.setCharAt(index, '!');
        buf.deleteCharAt(index+1);
        //buf.deleteCharAt(buf.length()-1);
        }
        // get last character from stringbuilder and delete
        //buf.deleteCharAt(buf.length()-1);


        } 

        }

        public void writeFile() {
        try {

        String content = buf.toString();

        File file = new File("C:/Users/Sybren/Desktop/test.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done");


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: the last what? the last charracter of the 12?

Comment: No the last exclamation mark in my current output

Comment: Do you basically want to get the file as a string, remove newlines, then output with a newline after every 12 chars?

Comment: I want to read the file, make some changes and write it to another file. One of the changes is to start a newline after every 12 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Update the code in which while reading the file you will take the decision :

```
        int sevenCount = 0;
        int fourteenCount = 0;
        int data = 0;
        while ((data = reader.read()) != -1) {
            sevenCount++;
            fourteenCount++;
            if(sevenCount==7)  
            {
                 buf.append("-");   // append - at every 7th character
                 sevenCount = 0;
            }
            if(fourteenCount==14)
             {
                 buf.append("\n");  // change line after evrry 14th character
                 fourteenCount = 0;
              }

            if(((char)data) == '*')
            {
                  char c = '!';    //Change the code when char contain *
                  data = (int)c;
             }
            else
            {
                  buf.append((char)data);   
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you mean "\n" instead of "\\n" and buf.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")); also works but I want to know how to start a new line after 12 characters thats the problem

Comment: @Sybren actually i am not able to access the attached file due to firewall so i missed pblm.Plz give me some time to give u proper answer.

Comment: @Sybren can u paste input and expected output rather than file is attached.

Comment: When I try to copy/paste the input/output here or in my question some characters change automatically (dont ask me why). So plz have a look at the provided links.

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't work only the first line has the correct length (which my code also did) and you replace a * by a ! but two following * have to be replaced by a !. Another thing is that I have to use .readLine() for reading instead of .read().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a newline in a string every 12 chars:

```
str = str.replaceAll(".{12}", "$0\n");
```

Comment: Nice approach, but the drawback is that the whole file needs to be loaded into a string for this to work. This will create issues for large files.

Comment: Unless your file is huge, I would use a StringBuffer to build up the new content, then pass its `toString()` through the above call then write that to the new file.